# comparing fetched data between two database

Tags: php, mysql, oracle

I am successfully connected to a mySQL database and oracle database,

how do I compare the table content and update mySQL table if something added/updated on Oracle table;
ex.

```
 MySql db                                                 Oracle  db

 STAFF                                                    STAFF
 1. Roy                                                   1.Roy
 2. Julz                                                  2.Julz
 3. Uzzel                                                 3.Uzzel
                                                          4.Kate
                                                          5.Cy
```

how do I do that everytime I run the script, I am thinking of UNION,EXIST etc.
is there a better way to do this? so this would be the result.

```
MySql db                                                 Oracle  db

 STAFF                                                    STAFF
1. Roy                                                   1.Roy
2. Julz                                                  2.Julz
3. Uzzel                                                 3.Uzzel
4. Kate                                                  4.Kate
5. Cy                                                    5.Cy
```

I am using oci8 for oracle and pdo in php.. cant make pdo_oci run thats why I use oci8 :D thanks

Answer (score 0):

If MySql is always following the Oracle's db, why don't you just drop the table and import everything from Oracle? It is easier and should take similar amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Trying updating a file with the `update/insert` details (Like log the `DMLs` over you source table)

And write a listener program which listens for any change in your file, and it further process the corresponding change in your destination table.

You can implement the same way like IMPLEMENT a trigger for INSERT and UPDATE, and update a temp table. in your source database, and just refer the temp table now for updating your destination db.

**EDIT:** Let the intraday process do this kind of SYNC up, may be once a day or week, do a full dump export from Oracle to MySQL, or do a reconciliation.